# Problema al ejecutar Rsync y SSH con certificado de clave privada

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ssh, rsync

Estoy intentando hacer una copia de imágenes en forma dinámica desde un servidor a otro. El servidor clon está montado en un `Google Platform` por lo que la única forma de transferir archivos vía `ssh`o `rsync` o `sftp`, es con su correspondiente par de claves públicas y privadas.

Como la clave privada contiene un frase de contraseña, utilicé el siguiente comando para que no me la pidiera otra vez:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/mi_certificado.pem
```

Y luego para hacer la transferencia de archivos utilizo lo siguiente comando desde la terminal:

```
$ rsync  -e "ssh -i /home/pi/key.pem" -aq --rsync-path="mkdir -p /ruta/a/crear/ && rsync" /ruta/a/copiar/* usuario@host:/ruta/a/pegar/
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, funciona perfecto. Este `script` crea el árbol de directorio en el servidor remoto y transfiere las imágenes que hay en la carpeta local a la carpeta remota recién creada.

El problema sucede cuando hago exactamente lo mismo pero desde `python`, es decir:

```
import os    
os.system('rsync  -e "ssh -i /home/pi/key.pem" -aq --rsync-path="mkdir -p /ruta/a/crear/ && rsync" /ruta/a/copiar/ usuario@host:/ruta/a/pegar/')
```

**Nota:** También lo intenté con `subprocess.call()`

Y Aparece el siguiente error:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

No tengo idea porqué está intentando acceder a `ssh-askpass`, que no está instalado y no tengo por que instalarlo.

**Actualización**
Un antecedente más: el Script Python está corriendo como demonio con PM2 si lo corro directamente desde la terminal con `$> sudo mistript.py` funciona pero me pide que ingrese la frase de contraseña.

Como conclusión previa, creo que ni PM2 ni Python le hacen caso a la instrucción que si vale para la terminal (`ssh-add ~/.ssh/mi_certificado.pem`) ya que en ambos casos me están pidiendo la contraseña de la llave privada.

Answer (score 1):

En principio, creo que el problema reside en que el proceso `ssh` que lanza `rsync` no tiene información acerca del *socket* donde esta escuchando el agente SSH que ya tiene la clave de tu llave privada.

Por ello, intenta iniciar `ssh-askpass` el cual probablemente no encuentra porque el proceso no tiene un `$PATH` que contenga `/usr/bin`.

En la mayoría de los Linux de escritorio al iniciar una sesión un agente SSH (generalmente `ssh-agent` u otro, según el entorno de escritorio, como `gnome-keyring-daemon` en ambientes Gnome) que atiende las peticiones de autenticación usando un *socket*, y este se anuncia mediante la variable entorno `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Para solucionar tu problema, te sugiero usar `subprocess.call(cmd, env=env)` donde `env` debe alojar una variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` que puedes tomar de `os.environ`.

Un ejemplo más complejo* de algo similar esta en [este gist](https://gist.github.com/toolness/c75a3b5cef01ffc1bb2d9ba89c8da63e).

Espero te sirva!

--

- Que no he probando, pero se ve correcto